# RabbitMQ and Audiofiles

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message, bytestream, cloudamqp

How to send an audio file as message in Cloudamqp?

I'm guessing I need its byte stream and send it as a JSON. But I'm not sure if that is possible. Or do I just send the link of the location of the audio file for download?

Comment: Handling large messages on RabbitMQ might not be the best of moves.  Maybe your other idea is better, i.e. upload the audio file to another location, then send the location of the file within the message?

Answer (score 0):

The message body is a buffer, you can put what you prefer inside.

JSON, ANS1, XML or buffer audio.